# Hibernate PostUpdateEventListener is invoking for every Jpa call

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using Spring Data JPA with hibernate 5.3.7 core.I have written a custom listener that implements PostUpdateEventListener.My requirement is to invoke a callback method on each Database update i.e. only for update operation call of the entity.

But `onPostUpdate` of `PostUpdateEventListener` is invoking on every Jpa call i.e.  irrespective of DB operation. This is strange behavior for me. Or the listener behaves in same way?

I am using Hibernate 5.3.7 and not able to see much documentation in detail other than the following [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/spi/PostUpdateEventListener.html#requiresPostCommitHandling-org.hibernate.persister.entity.EntityPersister-)

Also attaching the classes which is used to register my custom listener and required configuration.

1. CustomEventListener class :

   ```
   import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
   import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

   import org.hibernate.event.spi.PostUpdateEvent;
   import org.hibernate.event.spi.PostUpdateEventListener;
   import org.hibernate.persister.entity.EntityPersister;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

   @Component
   public class CustomEventListener implements PostUpdateEventListener {

       /**
        * 
        */
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       public static final CustomEventListener INSTANCE = new CustomEventListener();
       @PersistenceContext
       private EntityManager entityManager;
       /* (non-Javadoc)
        * @see org.hibernate.event.spi.PostCollectionUpdateEventListener#onPostUpdateCollection(org.hibernate.event.spi.PostCollectionUpdateEvent)
        */

       @Override
       public boolean requiresPostCommitHanding(EntityPersister persister) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           return false;
       }

       /* (non-Javadoc)
        * @see org.hibernate.event.spi.PostUpdateEventListener#onPostUpdate(org.hibernate.event.spi.PostUpdateEvent)
        */
       @Override
       public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           System.out.println("hello");
       }

   }`
   ```
2. HibernateConfig class : used to configure `hibernate.integrator_provider` property in the existing configuration

   ```
   import java.util.Collections;
   import java.util.Map;

   import org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.IntegratorProvider;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernatePropertiesCustomizer;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

   /**
    * @author satyam.kaushik
    * @version  Last modified 09-Apr-2019
    */

   @Component
   public class HibernateConfig implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

       @Override
       public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
           hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.integrator_provider",
                   (IntegratorProvider) () -> Collections.singletonList(MetadataExtractorIntegrator.INSTANCE));
       }
   }
   ```
3. MetadataExtractorIntegrator class to register listener
       `

   ```
   import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
   import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
   import org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistry;
   import org.hibernate.event.spi.EventType;
   import org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator;
   import org.hibernate.service.spi.SessionFactoryServiceRegistry;

   public class MetadataExtractorIntegrator implements Integrator {

       public static final MetadataExtractorIntegrator INSTANCE = new MetadataExtractorIntegrator();

       @Override
       public void integrate(Metadata metadata, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
               SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {

           final EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry = serviceRegistry.getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);

           eventListenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_UPDATE, CustomEventListener.INSTANCE);

       }

       @Override
       public void disintegrate(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {

       }
   }`
   ```

   I also tried other in built listeners provided by API i.e. `SaveOrUpdateEventListener` or `MergeEventListener` but nothing is working for me. It looks like the listener is invoking for each JPA call instead of only update call.

Also attaching the below logs for the Get request which is causing issue (i.e. invoking listener method which should not suppose to call)

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Apr/2019:16:38:38 +0530] "OPTIONS /rippsadm/rest/device?sort-column=&sort-order=asc&page-no=1&page-size=15 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Apr/2019:16:38:38 +0530] "OPTIONS /rippsadm/rest/device/filter HTTP/1.1" 200 -

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Apr/2019:16:38:41 +0530] "GET /rippsadm/rest/device/filter HTTP/1.1" 200 1918

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Apr/2019:16:38:41 +0530] "GET /rippsadm/rest/device?sort-column=&sort-order=asc&page-no=1&page-size=15 HTTP/1.1" 200 6422

Comment: As soon as you modify the entity and it is attached to the entitymanager/session changes will be propagated automatically. You don't need an explicit `entityManager.merge` or `session.update` call for that. The issue is probably not in the listener but in the code that retrieves the entity and probably calls some setters/calculations on it.

Comment: Can you post the code that isn't suppose to trigger the update event?

Comment: Repository call :public Page<Device> findDeviceByDeleted(Character deleted,Pageable pageable);

Comment: Controller class method : @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getAllInstitutions(@RequestHeader(value = "X-Auth-Token") String xAuthToken) {
  try {/////service layer call
   }}

Comment: @M.Deinum : I am not doing any explicit call in listener method.You can see in the code snippet.I am printing hello there.There is no post call during  the Get service implementation.If you need access logs of server then I can share it explicitly.

Comment: Again it doesn't matter what you do, if you call a setter method or calculation method on the entity (the entity is important here) it will do an update. As mentioned you don't need to explicitly call update/merge/persist for an update to be triggered... Hence it depends on what you do i your code with the entity NOT what happens in the listener.

Comment: @M.Deinum I agree with you that could be one of the root cause. But in my case auditing was root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Customize the Handling of `EventType.POST_UPDATE` Events for the entities which doesn't need to post process but triggering update call to JPA for each request.

Identify if any insert statement executed during the Get call by using `show_sql=true`. If yes then there can be multiple reasons including auditing, some setter method update the entity in services, Or some interceptor invoke an insert/update call etc.

In my case hibernate enver auditing was root cause. Setting `show_sql=true` was showing the hibernate insert query for one of audit managed entity and `REVINFO` hibernate enver default table.

In my case this entity never need to post process.

Therefore I've added an if condition inside `onPostUpdate` method of Custom listener  to skip post processing for the entity resolved the issue.

```
@Override
public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {
    if(!(event.getEntity().getClass().getTypeName().contains("<EntityName>"))) {
        //do your post processing logic
    }
}
```